# Getting the majority element per row in numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Is there a quick way (so no for loops) to find the majority element per row in a numpy array and create a new array out of this?

For example, if you have the following numpy array:

```
X = 
[[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

you could do `get_majority(X)`, which would output

```
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
```

I've tried doing this by looping over the matrix and using a `Counter` from `collections`, but that's extremely slow for large matrices, so I want to find a vectorised way to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [Scipy's mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) -

```
from scipy.stats import mode

mode(X, axis=-1)[0]
```